# GETUTCDATE Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why should we use `GETUTCDATE()` function instead of `getdate()` or vice-verse?

What is the purpose of both? Please help me with example.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[GETUTCDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql) represents the current `UTC` time *(Universal Time Coordinate or Greenwich Mean Time)*

- It is a `nondeterministic` function, Views and expressions that reference this column cannot be indexed.

*The current UTC time is derived from the current local time and the time zone setting in the operating system of the computer on which SQL Server is running.*

The difference between `GETDATE()` and `GETUTCDATE()` is time ***zone number of the SQL Server machine***.

For better understanding see the example:

```
DECLARE @local_time DATETIME;
DECLARE @gmt_time DATETIME;
SET @local_time = GETDATE();
SET @gmt_time = GETUTCDATE();
SELECT 'Server local time: '
   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@local_time);
SELECT 'Server GMT time: '
   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@gmt_time);
SELECT 'Server time zone: '
   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),
      DATEDIFF(hour,@gmt_time,@local_time));
GO
```

OUTPUT:

```
Server local time: Jun  2 2007 10:06PM
Server GMT time: Jun  2 2007  4:21PM
Server time zone: 6
```

GETDATE ()

- It will return the date with your regional time or we can say, it returns the current system date and time.
- If you are connected to the SQL server remotely then the timestamp displayed will be the timestamp of the remote machine and not your local machine.
- It is a nondeterministic function.
- Views and expressions that reference this column cannot be indexed.

GETUTCDATE ()

- It will return the date and GMT time (Greenwich Mean Time).
- GETUTCDATE () can be used to store the timestamp that is independent of Time Zones.
- The current UTC time is derived from the current local time and the time zone setting in the operating system of the computer on which the instance of Microsoft SQL Server is running.
- GETUTCDATE is a nondeterministic function.
- Views and expressions that reference this column cannot be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

getdate() will return the date as is on your local system. Let's say you are pulling some data and the DB server is located on a UTC location. your date time columns will return UTC time stamps and you won't be able to match time stamps.

So you can adjust the date time by using datediff function on UTC date and getdate.